# Homegroup doesn't detect network cable

Tags: windows-8, home-networking, homegroup

We have 2 machines here in the network.

Both run (legal) Windows 8, both are in the same homegroup, for both machines the network is set up as a Private Network.

Copying files over wireless works like a charm albeit a little slow.

Now before I formatted my machine I could plug in a cable during the copying and Windows 8 would notice that both machines were also connected via cable and used the cable to copy over the files, it went from 5MB/sec to 100+ MB/sec.

The problem is that this doesn't happen anymore. It considers the cable connection as a public network, thus it doesn't allow the homegroup over that anymore.

Is there anyway I can tell that the machine that I am connected on is trusted?

Update:

MachineA and MachineB

When MachineA pings MachineB it get's back the IPV6 address that's assigned to the cabled network.

When MachineB pings MachineA it get's back an IPV4 address.

Update 2:

Disabling the firewall on MachineA for public networks results in being able to see the IPV6 address, and thus fast connection over cable.

Comment: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9837-network-location-set-private-public-windows-8-a.html

Comment: @Havenard no can do, since it's a pc<>pc connection, no router involved. I cannot set the network to private.

Comment: Doesn't matter. But if you have no router or gateway you gotta configure a static IP address for each machine, otherwise they wont be able to communicate.

Comment: @Havenard I disagree, why would it work in one direction but not the other?

Comment: What you mean it works one way but not the other?